# Two Windows servers in SAN

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-area-network

I have two Windows 2016 servers with QLogic HBA. Servers connect to a Brocade SAN switch. Servers can ping fabric via QLogic FC ping utility. But one server don't see the other. In "Target list" in "QConvergeConsole" WWN not listed.
New zone on Brocade with this WWN's created and applied.
What do I need to do to establish connectivity?

Comment: What do you mean by "one server don't see the other"? Servers should connect to *actual storage*, not between themselves... SANs are not used for computer-to-computer networking.

Comment: I mean I can't FC ping one server from other. And I don't see WWN in Target list in "QConvergeConsole".

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how SANs are supposed to work: you can only make connections from servers to *targets* (i.e. storage devices), not to other servers.

It would be completely useless to test connectivity between servers, because you'll never actually make a direct connection between two of them.

This is also confirmed by the [product documentation](https://www.marvell.com/docs/hpe/assets/hpe-marvell-appnote-2500-2600-storfusion-fcpingtraceroute.pdf):

> FC Ping and FC Trace Route are easily accessed within the QConvergeConsole® (QCC)
>   GUI management application, and provide a simple way to verify connectivity
>   between a SAN-connected server and storage device.

Please note the "between a SAN-connected server and storage device" part.

> What do I need to do to establish connectivity?

Nothing, if you can reach the targets from the servers then everything is fine; there is no need at all for the servers to talk to each other through the SAN: that is what actual network connections are for.

Answer (score 0):

The FC HBAs are not supposed to be connected directly. Some of them even do not allow direct connections to SAN devices without SAN switch between them.

Nevertheless, you can put FC storage target software onto one of the servers, effectively making it a SAN block access storage system. Or you may set up a virtual tape library software to emulate a backup storage. After that your initiator (the other server) will see all targets.

There's also another way to establish the connectivity. The craziest (but not impossible) FC usage is to set up IPFC protocol stack, to use the SAN as the LAN also. But all IPFC implementations I'm aware of lack the optimization and (by my personal experience) are far from being fast and efficient.